# SSH client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

Tags: ssh

I have been receiving this message frequently when I am inactive in an SSH connection.

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
```

I tried the following:

1. Add `ServerAliveInterval=86400` and `ServerAliveCountMax=14` to my config file.
2. Add `ServerAliveInterval=86400` and `ServerAliveCountMax=14` to my `sshd_config` file.
3. Use the `-o` flags to specify the `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax`.

But none of the above seems to work for my computer for some reason.

Comment: [Did you try](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34201/209677) also `TCPKeepAlive yes` on client side?

Comment: More than likely your connection between you and the Server is breaking, not yoru actual SSH *session* timing out or such.

Comment: I tried TCPKeepAlive yes and it still caused some issues. Right now, I have uninstalled and reinstalled the openssh-client so I am waiting to see if this will work.

Comment: Hmm... Yes, reinstalling did not work either. I will have to ask the admin's of the server to see if it is from their end.

Thanks for the help!